# Object methods are unavailable after including with require

Tags: node.js

I'm working through Node.js module, but I'm stuck on how to export a prototype in a way that makes the methods accessible.

For example, take the following code:

```
var myobj = function(param) {
  this.test = 'a test';
  return this.param = param;
};

myobj.prototype = {
  indexpage: function() {
    console.log(this.test);
    return console.log(this.param);
  }
};

var mo = new myobj('hello world!');
mo.indexpage();
```

My results are as expected:

```
a test
hello world!
```

---

If I take the same code and place it in another file with module.exports:

*somefile.js*

```
var myobj = function(param) {
  this.test = 'a test';
  return this.param = param;
};

myobj.prototype = {
  indexpage: function() {
    console.log(this.test);
    return console.log(this.param);
  }
};

// the only line that is different
module.exports = myobj;
```

*app.js code*

```
var MyObj = require('myobj.js');
var mo = new MyObj('hello world!');
mo.indexpage();
```

Now I get `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'indexpage'`

Where am I going wrong? I've been working on this single issue for hours; my basic grasp of javascript isn't helping me figure out this issue any more than searching forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are `return`ing a value from your constructor function.

```
var myobj = function(param) {
  this.test = 'a test';
  return this.param = param;
};
```

should be:

```
var myobj = function(param) {
  this.test = 'a test';
  this.param = param;
};
```

Because of the return, what you are really doing is

```
var mo = 'hello world!';
mo.indexpage();
```

Comment: Ah ha! I _knew_ messing around with coffeescript while I was learning node.js was a bad idea! But I learned something valuable because of it. Thanks!

Comment: Spoke too soon - now I don't have access to object properties in my methods - e.g. 'this.param', but only when I'm declaring my routes. Any ideas?

Comment: @JoBu1324 As long as you are calling the methods properly, that should work. If you are using CoffeeScript, you should probably also use it's class system, since it automatically disallows `return` inside constructor functions.